# How can I get the file creation date in a folder?

Tags: c#

I want to get the date creation of all the files in the folder and sort them, but if I use the following code then for all the files, I get the date creation of the folder:

```
DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(@"d:\images");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\images");
foreach (var file in files)
Console.WriteLine(file + " " + fileCreatedDate);
```

Comment: That's because your variable `fileCreatedDate` always contains the folder creation date. You should instead do `Console.WriteLine(file + " " + File.GetCreationTime(file));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're only getting the creation date of the folder. If you're just looking for the file creation date and not the folder, I would suggest moving `File.GetCreationTime()` into your `for` loop like so:

```cs
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\images");
foreach (var file in files){
    DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(@"d:\images\", file)); // Append the file name to the end of your path
    Console.WriteLine(file + " " + fileCreatedDate);

    // Additional logic
}
```